# Error: need a repository as argument?

Tags: 12.04

how to fix this problem?! Help me please !!
mizo@mizo-OptiPlex-GX270:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa: upubuntu-com/icons2
Error: need a repository as argument

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a *blank* between `ppa:` and `upubuntu-com/icons2`. The line must read

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/icons2
```